# javascript stops working only below a certain line in the code

Tags: javascript, href, getelementbyid

the weird thing is that the code works, and below a certain line nothing will work, not even an alert, and variable loses value!

the code is quite simple:

```
// retrieving scroll position from a hidden text input<br>
var scrollPos = document.getElementById("scrollPosition").value;

// at this point scrollPos value is a certain number :)

// so i'm successfully able to change the HREF accordingly! :)<br>
document.getElementById("page1").href = "page1.php?pos="+scrollPos;<br>
document.getElementById("page2").href = "page2.php?pos="+scrollPos;<br>
document.getElementById("page3").href = "page3.php?pos="+scrollPos; // same value to all!

document.getElementById("page4").href = "page4.php?pos="+scrollPos;<br>
// at some weird point scrollPos loses its value! :(
```

actually, nothing after the glitch point works, not even an alert("test")!

Comment: Hi mimmo, did you get this working?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `document.getElementById("something")`, and there is no element on the page with id `"something"`, Javascript will return `null`. If you then try to access the `href` property of `null`, Javascript throws an exception and halts all processing.

You can open up the Javascript console in your browser to see error messages, like `TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null`.

You could do something like this to avoid both that error and having to hard-code the number of pages in general:

```
var page, elem;
for (page = 1; elem = document.getElement("page"+page); ++page) {
  elem.href = "page" + page + ".php?pos=" + scrollPos;
}
```

Comment: That's wrong, the browser will return `null`. Then it will try to access to the `href` property of `null`, and that's what will make it crash.

Comment: True, @MaëlNison.  Corrected.

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Once the page is loaded (with chrome) i right click the elements and click on "inspect element" and they all have their "id"s set correctly!! :(

Comment: hold on, i think you're right, i tried the firefox firebug and i get this message:

"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

but still, when i check the source code, i have all the id set correctly!!! why is that? THANK you for your time!!! i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
var p4 = document.getElementById("page4");
if (p4) p4.href = "page4.php?pos="+scrollPos;
```

Comment: thank you, but i think it still wouldn't work, i have a problem when javascript executes: in firebug i get the message: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

I'm still struggling with this, i think that Mark Reed and Maël Nison nailed the problem, but i still can't figure out why it is happening.

Basically i have 2 buttons in the website which include sub-menu links with a drop-down panel (i am using "anylinkmenu" for the dropdown), i had to add some code inside the anylinkmenu.js to add an "id" to every "a href" element, no biggie.

Only the first dropdown would have the "id" recognized by my "js" code, the second dropdown wouldn't work for doughnuts!

Thank you again for your help!!